# Why does the definition of differential is defined in this way?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, intuition, differential

I would like to have a intuitive view of the definition of differential in the page 127 of Carmo's differential geometry book:

[image]

Why does we define differential in this way? In other words, why is this particular vector $d_p(w)$ so important? This choice seems arbitrary to me.

**EDIT:**

*Definition of differential map*:

We say $F$ is differentiable at $p\in U$ if its component functions are differentiable at $p$; that is, by writing

$$F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\ldots,f_m(x_1\ldots,x_n))$$

the functions $f_i,i=1,\ldots,m$, have continuous partial derivatives of all orders at $p$. $F$ is differentiable in $U$ if it is differentiabe at all points in $U$.

Comment: Why does it seem arbitrary to you? What would you like to do instead?

Comment: @B.Pasternak because I don't understand the intuition behind this definition.

Comment: Have you seen the formula for the action of $dF_p(w)$ on a smooth function? This should help. Also, I think the principle of "what else should we define it to be" applies here. We have a a curve and a map from one space to another, what can be possibly do?

Comment: @B.Pasternak it doesn't depend on the curve. Therefore I see in this way: we fix a point $p$ and define a map which take a vector $w$ to another vector $d_p(w)$. So what the relation between these two vectors (intuitively speaking)?

Comment: But it does depend on the curve. Well, at least on the local behaviour of the curve, i.e. the equivalence class of the curve.

Comment: @amd Why do you say that? The differential of a smooth map $F:M\to N$ at a point $p\in M$ is a map $dF_p:T_pM\to T_{F(p)}N$, hence $dF_p(v)$ is definitively a vector.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Oops. I was thinking of $dF_p$ itself.

Comment: What does do Carmo mean by "differentiable map" to begin with?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Please see my edit, I explain this there

Comment: In that case, the differential of a map is simply the linear map given by all the partial derivatives. Later on, when working with abstract manifolds, do Carmo's definition makes a lot of sense, but in Euclidean space, I don't see the point in using it. It could be a good exercise, though, to see that do Carmo's definition coincides with the one suggested here.

Comment: OK, I can think of one good reason to bear do Carmo's definition in mind; this definition is *intrinsic*. That is, it doesn't use coordinates. Once again, this is important mainly when working with abstract manifolds, but it may be good to start getting used to coordinate-free language at an early stage.